# How small can you make a planet or moon and still have dust devils on its surface?

Tags: atmosphere, moons, wind

I want a moon for one of my planets to be larger than the Moon, enough to have an appreciable atmosphere, but not quite so massive as Mars. I'd like it to be that if you were to land on it, the thin atmosphere would be able to blow dust around and create small dust devils that are at least visible to human eyes and transporting dust around. How much more massive than the Moon does it need to be before that becomes possible?

Comment: According to the Font of All Knowledge, the Moon had an [atmosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_the_Moon) at one time.

Comment: It's not really about the size so much as the atmosphere, Titan has a gravity not all that greater than our moon yet has a very respectable atmosphere so it's not al about gravity if you have sufficient outgassing from the body, gravity does help of course but it's not about ''size' so much as mass, imagine our moon was mostly composed of gold or lead, someone in a sci fi novel compressed the moon into a smaller body which increased the gravity, because you're closer to more of it and gravity falls off with distance that works, substituting gold or lead for much of it would do the same. –

Comment: @Pelinore - To be clear, when I'm talking about massiveness I'm talking about mass. Titan's atmosphere only exists because it is so far from the sun. If you brought it in closer, it would not be able to maintain such a thick atmosphere in the face of the solar wind.

Comment: Fair point perhaps, I'd have to check to be sure how fair so I'll take your word for it, though it would still be a case of how fast atmospheric components were outgassed from the body compared to how fast it was stripped, I suspect at it's current rate Titan would still have a substantially more appreciable atmosphere than our moon if it was as close to the sun .. high gold or lead content (due to whatever fluke of chance) to increase it's gravity isn't challenged as a suggestion I note?

Comment: @Pelinore - I would suspect that if Titan was as close as the moon from the beginning it would have lost its atmosphere at a similar rate, and all the frozen and liquid hydrocarbons would have boiled off and the water ice would sublimate. Elemtilas mentions the early atmosphere of the Moon, but that disappeared in 70 million years it seems. The gold or lead suggestion is interesting, but I'm thinking more of a naturally occurring moon.

Comment: @Axion Sorry, but no, or at least probably not, because Titan is still outgassing at a prodigious rate (geological activity), it's replacing atmosphere as it's being stripped which is almost certainly part of why it has such a thick atmosphere for its size, it could be stripped faster but the question is how fast would you have to strip it to match what it's putting out and keep it atmosphere free.

Comment: @Pelinore - It would be difficult to form an icy body like Titan close to the sun, but if we imagine it just plonked into orbit replacing Earth's moon 4.53 billion years ago, it certainly wouldn't have a thick Nitrogen atmosphere. Its escape velocity simply isn't high enough. Perhaps methane and ethane are big enough molecules to be held onto under the flux it would receive (not sure), but if it didn't exceed the Armstrong Limit, then instead of being a water world, it would boil off to bare rock like the moon.

Comment: @Axion [rolls eyes] I wasn't proposing an icy body like Titan, I was merely using Titan to illustrate that outgassing (for whatever reason) can counter atmosphere loss to solar winds > thus that a geologically active moon (of whatever composition) is a device you can use to explain a thicker atmosphere than might otherwise be expected.

Comment: Keep in mind, the moon had a magnetosphere for two billion years, so if the planet is young, and terraformed, you could have a body the size of the moon, or smaller with dust devils. If it's naturally habitable, that scenarios far less likely, though if the planets only native life is bacteria it's still a possibility, though again, it would need to stay in the first two billion year window of the planet in concern.

Answer (score 1):

The ability of a world to retain atmosphere doesn't depend on its surface gravity but on its escape velocity.  In order for a world to retain atmosphere for along time, the escape velocity has to be several times the speed of gas atoms and molecules in the world's exosphere, the upper atmospheric layers where gas particle escape into space.

https://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/commercial_books/2007/RAND_CB179-1.pdf

As it happens, the speed of gas particles in the exosphere is determined by their temperature, and the temperatures in the exosphere of Earth, for example, are several times as high as the temperatures at the surface of the Earth.

And it is the belief that the temperatures in the exospheres of planets are determined by the amount of ultraviolet radiation, especially the far ultraviolet, which the planets receive from their stars, while the surface temperatures at the surfaces of planets are mostly determined by the amount of visible and infrared radiation which they receive from their stars.

The Earth orbits the Sun with a semi-major axis of 1 Astronomical unit (AU) while  Saturn and its moons, including Titan, orbits the Sun with a semi-major axis of 9.5826 AU.

Earth has a surface gravity of 9.80665 meters per second per second, or 1 *g*, and an escape velocity of 11.186 kilometers per second.  Titan, the largest moon of Saturn, has a surface gravity of 1.352 meters per second per second, 0.138 *g*, and an escape velocity of 2.641 kilometers per second, 0.236 that of Earth. Thus it is seen that the ratio of a world's surface gravity divided by that of Earth will often be different from the ratio of that world's escape velocity divided by that of Earth.  A world's surface gravity and escape velocity need to be calculated separately.

https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/acceleration-due-to-gravity

https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/escape-velocity

Saturn and Titan orbit the Sun at 9.5826 times the distance Earth orbits the Sun.  Thus the amount of energy which Titan receives from the Sun is equal to the amount Earth gets from the Sun divided by 9.5826 squared.  9.5826 squared is 91.826, so Titan gets about 1/91.826 or 0.01089 times as much radiation from the Sun as Earth gets.

So Titan gets about 0.01089 times as much visible light and infrared radiation from the Sun to warm its surface as Earth gets, and so Titan is much colder than Earth.  And Titan gets about 0.01089 times as much ultrviolet radiation from the Sun to warm its exosphere as Earth gets, and so the exosphere of Titan is much colder than the exosphere of Earth.

And that means that Titan is much better able to retain an atmosphere than it would be if it orbited the Sun at a distance of 1 AU.

And in fact, Titan has a significant atmosphere, mostly nitrogen like Earth's atmosphere, and actually even denser than the atmosphere of Earth.

If you want your fictional world that is small and has a low escape velocity to be habitable for liquid water using life in general, or for humans in particular, the surface has to receive approximately as much energy as Earth gets from the Sun, while the exosphere has to receive as little ultraviolet radiation as possible, maybe no more than Titan gets.

One way to do that would be to make your world orbit a star which is much cooler than the Sun, and so emits a much smaller fraction of its radiation in the ultraviolet. Thus if your world orbited the cooler star close enough to get as much visible and infrared radiation as Earth gets, and so have as warm a surface as Earth, it would receive much less ultraviolet radiation and have a much cooler exosphere than Earth and thus be able to retain an atmosphere with a much lower escape velocity than Earth.

And the second way would be to make your world a moon orbiting a gas giant planet.  If a moon orbits a giant planet close enough and an eccentric enough orbit, tidal interactions with the planet will cause tidal heating of the moon's interior, and that interior heat will heat up the surface of the Moon.  It has been calculated that there is a distance around a giant planet called the habitable edge, and any moon which orbits closer to a planet than the habitable edge will get too much tidal heating and suffer from a runaway greenhouse effect.

So if a planet orbited its star at a distance where it didn't get enough radiation from the star for water to be liquid on the surface of its moon, that moon might have enough internal heat for tidal heating to have liquid water on the surface, if that moon orbited not far outside the tidal edge.  And the amount of ultraviolet radiation the moon received might be low enough for it to retain a substantial atmosphere even with a low escape velocity.

And if a planet orbited a star much cooler than the Sun at a great distance, but its moon was heated by tidal heating, both factors might combine to give it a low enough amount of ultraviolet radiation to have a substantial atmosphere with a low escape velocity.

Now you have to consider where you want your story to be in the scale of Science fiction hardness.

https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/SlidingScale/MohsScaleOfScienceFictionHardness

If you don't mind your story having a low scale, you can just assume that everything will work out all right and your small world with a low escape velocity like Titan can be warm enough for liquid surface water while having a low enough levels of ultraviolet radiation to keep its atmosphere for geological eras of time.

But if you want your story to have a high science fiction score, then you may need help from experts in one or more scientific fields to find out if your small world can retain a breathable atmosphere.

Does your world have to be habitable for humans?

If not, humans can wear spacesuits as they explore that that world or live in enclosed habitats on its surface.

Humans would need pressure suits on Mars, and controlgroup's answer says that there are dust devils on Mars.

A world with Titan's escape velocity, lower than that of Mar's can have an atmosphere at least dense as Mars's in some circumstances.  Of course Titan as it is has a surface that is mostly methane ice with bodies of liquid methane.  I doubt that an icy world would have much dust on its surface.

Thus a world with Titan's escape velocity and atmospheric retention capability would have to be made mostly of rock.  It would probably form in the inner star system without much ice and migrate outward to where the flux of ultraviolet radiation would be low enough for it to retain its atmosphere. A rocky world with the same escape velocity as Titan would have a higher average density and so would be much smaller in diameter.

And it is possible that a world with an even lower escape velocity than Titan might have visible dust devils in its atmosphere.

Triton, the largest moon of Neptune, has an escape velocity of 1.455 kilometers per second, or 0.130 that of Earth.  And a very, very thin atmosphere of mostly nitrogen.

Axion's comments to controlgroup's answer said that the winds on Triton would be able to lift micrometer size particles, but Axion said that you wouldn't be able to see such dust.  But I think that if the dust particles were concentrated densely enough in the atmosphere, you could see them in a dust devil.

So it may be possible that some worlds with escape velocities as low as 1.455 kilometers per second might possibly have visible dust devils.

Answer (score 0):

### As long as it can have an appreciable atmosphere, as small as you want.

Did you know that Mars has dust devils? In fact, they have posed an issue for rovers - if a dust devil throws dust onto a rover's solar panels, it can be an issue for the continued operation of the rover (or sometimes, dust devils can actually *clean* the solar panels). Mars has a very tenuous atmosphere and lower gravity than Earth, but it nonetheless has dust devils.

So, as long as you can keep an atmosphere as dense as Mars's (which has a pressure of about 0.0065 atm - very low by human standards) and a surface gravity enough to keep it (using Mars as a baseline, about 37% of Earth gravity), you're pretty much guaranteed to have dust devils.

As far as physical size goes, the surface gravity is proportional to the planet's mass and inversely proportional to the square of the radius; mass being proportional to the density and to the cube of the radius, the surface gravity is thus proportional to the density and to the radius of the planet. So, if you make the moon extra dense, you can make it very small before it starts to lose its atmosphere.

To answer, **you can make the moon as small as you want.** Just increase the density proportionally so that the surface gravity stays around 0.37 *g* (up to a maximum of 22.5 tons per cubic meter, at which point the moon is entirely made of iridium and can't be made more dense), and the atmosphere of around 0.0065 atm should be held tight to the moon by gravity, and dust devils should appear all over the place.

Naturally, since Mars exists, **any appropriately-dense moon sized between the Moon and Mars should be able to retain an atmosphere of the right pressures to allow for dust devils.**

Comment: "Naturally, since Mars exists, any appropriately-dense moon sized between the Moon and Mars should be able to retain an atmosphere of the right pressures to allow for dust devils."

The Moon doesn't have a sufficient atmosphere to host dust devils, but Mars does. Mars is nearly 9 times the mass of the moon so that's a wide range. Further out objects can have thicker atmospheres for the same mass because it's colder, so an intermediate atmospheric pressure might be that of Triton. I don't think you'd see little ice twisters on its surface though.

Comment: My point being that, since Mars exists and has dust devils, any celestial object with surface characteristics not deviating substantially from Mars should also have dust devils.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally hit return before finishing my comment, without holding shift for paragraphs.

My question is about what would the minimum threshold be. A Mars' sized moon is fairly sizeable. I'm not sure if it can be shown that's the minimum size. Triton's winds can pick up micrometer sized particles with ~400 times less pressure than Mars, but you wouldn't be able to see that dust.

Answer (score 0):

Wild idea, but lets assume the planet is negatively charged.
Now there is a world - like a gas giant nearby, throwing radiation and accelerated particles in large .

Now there being no atmosphere the dust-devils wouldn't dance-
unless, the whole thing would be kneeded into erruptions, the errupted particles charged statically by the generator in the sky nearby. Then you would have towering duststorms discharging to ground, whirling in invisible em-winds and glittering when hit by sped up particles and radiation.